# Shell crash and how to debug it

Tags: shell, c, system-calls

As part of my C application running on Linux, I call a script using the `system( )` library function. This script does a umount of a connected USB flash drive. Very rarely (1 in 7-8k) iterations, I see a segmentation fault,

/bin/sh: line 1: 18083 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)

I have verified with debug prints that the failure appears due to the system(). This appears to be a shell crash.
I need to understand why a segmentation fault occurred.

My script contains the following code:

```
mount | grep "USB"
ret=$?
if [ $ret == "0" ]; then
    umount -l /mnt/USB
    ret=$?;
    if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
        rmdir /mnt/USB
    fi
fi
```

gdb isn't available on that platform and considering this issue occurs very rarely, it is tough to debug it.

Comment: I'd suspect a dodgy USB driver. Can you put lots of logging into the shell script to see exactly which command is failing? (or maybe just run it `-x`)

Comment: Your script can be shortened to `mount | grep -qF 'USB' && umount -l /mnt/USB && rmdir /mnt/USB`, but I suspect you also want to `grep` for `/mnt/USB` instead of just `USB`.

Comment: Have you fed the core dump into the debugger? You can see where it went wrong. You can do it on a different machine. Are you checking return codes?

Comment: Nitpick: `system` is not a system call. It's a standard C library function.

Comment: if the segfault comes from `sh`, it's not an issue with your program. But that's a simple enough script, it would be unlikely to trigger any issues in any common shell, either. Could it be a hardware problem?

Comment: The error message looks modified, the initial `/` on `/bin/sh` is missing (either from the text in the question or your script has a problematic `#!`-line). What is the real error message and what does your call to `system()` look like in your code?  Does the script contain a `#!` line and is it executable?

Comment: What is actually crashing here?  You have 1) a C program 2) a shell script run by `/bin/sh` 3) `mount` called on line 1 4) `grep` called on line 1.  If it is your C program crashing (1) could you please try with a dummy scrip with one line: `echo hello world`.  This will help narrow down the problem.  The error message smells like shell (2) is crashing.

Comment: @Kusalananda the line is /bin/sh: line 1: 18083 Segmentation fault (core dumped) The script has the initial lines: #!/bin/sh
Yes the script is executable.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Yes it appears that shell is crashing Under what instance does shell crash?

Comment: Why don't you do this from C?

Comment: @Kusalananda that could be the last resort.. any idea why shell crashes and how to debug this

Comment: Do you have `coredumpctl` on your system? If you do, it should help produce a stack trace from the crash, even without gdb installed... That might be helpful to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

[strace](https://strace.io/) could help. AFAIK it's available in the default yum/apt/whatever repos.

`strace` is a diagnostic, debugging and instructional userspace utility for Linux. It is used to monitor and tamper with interactions between processes and the Linux kernel, which include system calls, signal deliveries, and changes of process state.

System administrators, diagnosticians and trouble-shooters will find it invaluable for solving problems with programs for which the source is not readily available since they do not need to be recompiled in order to trace them.